# Best practice to make Config object available inside Controller and Model

Tags: php, model-view-controller

On application start I'm creating Config object (Singleton). How could I make Config object be available inside Model and Controller? Should I pass Config object to constructor as method parametr or I should better use $this->config = Config::getInstance()? Any other methods?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton is essentially just fancy syntax for a global variable, and is as bad as globals are (and they *are* bad). Passing a parameter is the cleanest option as it creates no hard coupling between classes and allows for maximum flexibility. Another reasonable (but rather advanced) option is to use a dependency injection container, see for example [this post](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/11/bucket-is-a-minimal-dependency-injection-container-for-php/).

Comment: Reading now your link - very interesting, especially this article http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/02/04/dealing-with-dependencies/ By the way, please could you tell me why globals are considered to be  bad way?

Comment: ...probably. I'm just starting to do some OOP in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If `Config` is a Singleton, you can use pretty much any solution you'd like :

- Passing it as a parameter is not needed, as it's global

  - But passing is as a parameter can allow for dependancy injection -- which might help if you want some automated tests
- Storing it as a class property can be useful -- but it's not required either.

Generally, for that kind of object, I just use `Config::getInstance()` each time I need it, and don't store it in a class property.

But I guess this is a matter of personnal preferences...

Answer (score 0):

I usually make it a instance singleton by means of `Config::getInstance()`, and add accesors in `Environment#config` (or `Bootstrap#config` , tutorials go with Bootstrap) and `My_Top_Controller#config` (this My_Top_Controller extends Zend_Controller and is the ancestor of all other controllers) and also add it to Zend_Registry via config key.